# What is the difference? "had feared" vs "feared" vs "was feared"

Tags: past-tense

Which one should I use:

> I **had feared** that my companion would talk too much.
>
> I **was feared** that my companion would talk too much.
>
> I **feared** that my companion would talk too much.

Comment: "I had feared" puts the completed action in the past as viewed from a more recent past. "I feared" puts the action in the past as viewed from the present. "I was feared _that_ sth" in meaningless unless "fear" is used in the archaic transitive sense, or in the dialectical usage preserved in remote regions as _I'm afeared_ for _I'm afraid._

Comment: What Mr. Dant said. Which one should you use? *Not the second one*. However, this would be grammatical and acceptable: _I was fearing that my companion would talk too much._